# Glr, como eu faço para deixar o elemento que foi criado fixo na página mesmo que a página seja carregada? Pq quando carrega a página ele some

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var listagem = document.getElementById("listagem");

function createNewElement() {
  // Cria a div
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("id", "d");

  // Cria a li
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute("id", "li");

  // Cria o botão
  var check = document.createElement("input");
  check.setAttribute("id", "check");
  check.type = "checkbox";

  // Pega o valor do input digitado
  var texto = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  li.innerText = texto;

  // Adiciona a lista 
  div.appendChild(check);
  div.appendChild(li);
  listagem.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Se não me engano a informação de que estes elementos já foram criados devem ser armazenados de alguma forma, como num `LocalStorage` para gerar os elementos quando a página é carregada, se já tiverem sido geradas anteriormente.

Comment: Obg, mas tem como vc me mostrar um exemplo?(Pq sou um "iniciante")

Comment: Coloca o HTML na pergunta tb.

Comment: Coloquei o html e js logo ali em baixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara o suficiente para nós podermos te ajudar. Mas na minha perspectiva o que você está querendo fazer é tentar pegar o `value` de um `input="text"` e colocá-lo no interior de algum elemento qualquer e mesmo se a página for carregada ou se você fechar a página o texto ainda permanecera no elemento especificado. Para isso, você teria que usar um recurso que salvasse o `value` do campo `input="text"` dentro do elemento especificado, mas em seu computador. Para isso, você pode usar a *API* de armazenamento local no caso [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage) existe também a [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), mas no seu caso use a `localstorage` para os dados não serem perdidos. Eu criei um exemplo simples do zero para você, pois o seu exemplo não iria bater muito com o meu e ficaria confuso para você entender, não vou falar a respeito do que eu fiz no código, pois no próprio código está comentado. Pode ser que aqui no *stackoverflow* retorne erro. Não sei, pode ser que eu esteja errado, mas deve ser por motivos de segurança por estar usando uma *API* de armazenamento local. Mas o código em si está funcionando normalmente.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Você vai digitar o nome nessa caixa -->
  <input id="new-name" type="text" placeholder="Nome:">
  <!-- Esse botão é o que vai salvar os dados que você digito caixa de texto -->
  <button id="button-new-name" type="button">Novo Nome</button>
  <!-- Esse é o que vai remover -->
  <button id="button-delete-name">Apagar Nome</button>
  <!-- Aqui é aonde vai aparecer o texto que você digitou na caixa de texto -->
  <p id="paragraph"></p>
  <script>
  
    // Variáveis com valores fazendo referência aos atributos id no html.
    let newName = window.document.querySelector("#new-name");
    let buttonNewName = window.document.querySelector("#button-new-name");
    let buttonDeleteName = window.document.querySelector("#button-delete-name");
    let paragraph = window.document.querySelector("#paragraph");

    // O contéudo do parágrafo vai receber o valor da chave Nome.
    // Isso é para quando você carregar a página o nome continuar lá.
    paragraph.textContent = window.localStorage.getItem("Nome");

    // Adicionar um evento de click no button com id button-new-name e chame uma função anônima.
    buttonNewName.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        // Quando o botão for clicado criar uma chave Nome com o valor do valor de input com id="new-name".
        window.localStorage.setItem("Nome", newName.value);
        // Quando o botão for clicado pegar o valor da chave nome e colocar no parágrafo.
        paragraph.textContent = window.localStorage.getItem("Nome");
        newName.value = "";
    });

    // Adicionar um evento de click no button com id button-delete-name e chame uma função anônima.  
    buttonDeleteName.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        // Remover a chave Nome que está armazenada no seu PC.
        window.localStorage.removeItem("Nome");
        // O contéudo do paragrafo vai receber nada. Isso é, uma string vazia.
        paragraph.textContent = "";
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Com esse exemplo provavelmente vou conseguir resolver meu "problema", mas esse storage salva as tag criadas? Tipo, `document.createElement("p");`?

Comment: Desculpa qualquer coisa, eu sou bem leigo ainda na parte de programação.

Comment: Cara, quando você coloca qualquer tag dentro de um documento e depois carrega a página elas já são renderizadas não a necessidade de salvá-las. Mas caso você tenha algum texto digitado em um input que nem o exemplo que eu dei na resposta, você teria que armazená-los no computador isso porque quando você voltar a carregar a página tudo vai voltar no padrão e os dados contidos no input não permanecerá lá.

Comment: Foi assim que eu pensei em fazer essa check list, esse método foi o mais simples que consegui fazer. Eu quero fazer uma check list de atividades, se vc tiver outra forma que possa me ajudar eu agradeço, Abçs.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui o código completo.
O html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/list.png">
  <title>Check List</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="main">
    <form action="#">
        <div class="new">
            <input type="text" id="texto">
            <button id="btn">add</button>
            <img src="img/reload.png" onclick="location.reload();">
        </div>
        <div class="lista">
            <ol class="listagem" id="listagem">
            </ol>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="js/js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

O js:

```
var listagem = document.getElementById("listagem");

function createNewElement() {
  // Cria i Para receber o icon
  var icon = document.createElement("i");
  icon.setAttribute("id", "icon");
  // Cria a div 
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("id", "d");
  // Cria a li
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute("id", "li");
  // Cria o botão 
  var check = document.createElement("input");
  check.setAttribute("id", "check");
  check.type = "checkbox";
  // Pega o valor do input digitado
  var texto = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  li.innerText = texto;
  // Adiciona a lista 
  div.appendChild(check);
  li.appendChild(icon);
  div.appendChild(li);
  listagem.appendChild(div);
}


function verificarCheck() {
  var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  var check = document.querySelectorAll("input#check");

  for (let i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
          if (check[i].checked) {
              check[i].style.display = "block";
              li[i].style.textDecoration = "line-through";
              //icon[i].setAttribute("class", "material-icons");
              //icon[i].innerText = "add";
          } else {
              // Nada
          }
        }
    }
}
setInterval(verificarCheck, 100);

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    var texto = document.getElementById("texto").value;
    if (texto) {
        createNewElement();
        document.getElementById("texto").value = "";
    } else {
        // Nada
    }
});
```